# Inserting (splicing?) an Array into another Array without apply

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say we have two Arrays in JavaScript, `[3,4,7]` and `[5,6]`.

Without sorting or using .apply, what is the best way to insert `[5,6]` into `[3,4,7]` at index 2 in order to achieve the resulting Array: `[3,4,5,6,7]`?

Comment: Do you want this specific case, or a general solution?

Comment: I mean in general. Forget the content, it's only an example sequence.

Comment: May I know why you don't want to use `apply`?

Comment: Sounds like a homework... Why sort or apply can't be use?

Comment: Only because I'm not really sure I understand why that is a good solution?  I may change the question if that's the best way anyone can think of.

Comment: @Dalorozo Sort is irrelevant.  I'm trying to insert a two value array into another array.  If the values were not numbers or were random, sort would not work.  I am trying to be brief.

Comment: Don't know how you're defining "best way", but you can do this: `a.slice(0,2).concat(b,a.slice(2))`. Unless you're saying you actually want to mutate the `a` Array.

Comment: Cookie Monster, please put that in an answer because that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how you're defining "best way", but you can do this:

```
a.slice(0,2).concat(b,a.slice(2));
```

Unless you're saying you actually want to mutate the `a` Array, in which case you could do this:

```
var c = a.splice(2);

for (var i = 0; i < b.length + c.length; i++) {
    a.push(i < b.length ? b[i] : c[i-b.length]);
}
```

This behavior of `.splice()` to split the Array in two parts may have issues in older IE that would need to be patched.

---

Or this would probably be better:

```
var c = b.concat(a.splice(2));

for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    a.push(c[i]);
}
```

Same caveat about `.splice()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function splice(arrayOne, arrayTwo, index) {
     var result = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
         if (i == index) {
             result = result.concat(arrayTwo);
         }

        result.push(arrayOne[i]);
     }

     return result;         
}
```

Comment: Just confirmed that this works. I edited my previous line in the if-statement, as I didn't realize that the concat function doesn't actually alter the corresponding array.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you don't want to use the native methods, but here's a fairly naive solution with just loops:

```
function doInsert(index, items, arr) {
    var insertLen = items.length,
        current;

    for (i = 0; i < insertLen; ++i) {
        current = i + index;
        arr[current + insertLen - 1] = arr[current];
        arr[current] = items[i];
    }
}

var arr = [3, 4, 7];
doInsert(2, [5, 6], arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Because if I had said `['4', 'z', '6', '2']` then sort would be irrelevant. I chose sequential numbers for simplicity.

Would you have used `.apply()` here?

Comment: @bitfed: `arr.splice.apply(arr, [2, 0].concat([5, 6]))` is a bit shorter. Why would you write your own solution if you already have t tools for that built-in?

Comment: Agreed, using the above is better, from your question I inferred you were looking to roll your own solution.

Comment: I am Evan, I guess my problem is not understanding the logic of why someone would choose apply without knowing this trick already?

Comment: I don't really follow, are you asking why someone would use a method if they didn't know about it?